# Alter a template whether a user is logged-in or not

Tags: 7, theming

In a theme, I am using the following preprocess function.

```
function dtv_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // Determine if the user is logged-in.
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    // Add a theme hook suggestion.
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__youtube_media__auth';
  } 
}
```

Inside /templates/node there are two files.

- node--youtube_media.tpl.php
- node--youtube_media__auth.tpl.php

By now there is no change happening whether a user is logged-in or not.

Does someone see the error and is able to enlighten me?

Comment: Maybe due to misspelling `media` in the template name?

Comment: corrected this and cleard cache but nothing happened either.

Comment: Theme debug says it uses the template froom the bas theme but not from the sub theme right now

Comment: `node__youtube_media__auth` 2 underlines before auth while `node--youtube_media_auth.tpl.php` there is only 1 underline before auth. Could that be it?

Comment: seems to be a typo in here corrected that either. May be it is the Content types name I am not shure were to use high fins ad where to use low fins exactly

Comment: If you take the login if statement out, does it work?